# Using Json to pass variables to JS in the Cart summary in PrestaShop

Tags: php, ajax, json, prestashop

I know that PS uses **Json** to recive the variables from controllers. For example in cart-summary.js there is:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
async: true,
cache: false,
data: 'controller=cart&ajax=true&allowSeperatedPackage=true&value='
+ ($(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0')
+ '&token='+static_token
+ '&allow_refresh=1',
success: function(jsonData)
{
//some functions...
}
```

I belive that the variables / arrays are pass from the **cart.php**. My question is which function / method in **cart.php** is responsible for passing the data ?

Tip: there is now **jsonEncode** or **echo** in the cart.php

My purpose is the pass some variables to cart-summary.js from the other controller.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb Prestashop platform ajax request works with an url structured such that:
Frontend request:

> controller=xxx

determine the controller that should be called for the request, in this case 'cart' means that CartController.php will be asked to manage the call.

> ajax=true

means that the request will be ajax, and the response need to be converted in json by the controller before outputting.

> token=xxx

it's the token used for internal authentication, and used by any controller to be sure that there's no fake/external request in place.

Backend management:

once the controller it's called the POST/PUT data it's always processed by the **postProcess** function, that any controller has and extend from the it's parent base controller.

In this specific case, if you open the CartController you will see a postProcess function, that analyzes all the parameter you pass to it (allowSeperatedPackage, allow_refresh, etc) to generate a response after having processed all the element as requested. 
For example in the call you linked the allowSeperatedPackage will trigger the following subcall in the controller

```
elseif (Tools::getIsset('changeAddressDelivery'))
                $this->processChangeProductAddressDelivery();
```

that will update a parameter in the cart of the user with

```
$this->context->cart->allow_seperated_package = (boolean)Tools::getValue('value');
$this->context->cart->update();
die('{"error":false}');
```

Beware that the GET of the products in specifically the cart-summary page it's made on the ParentOrderController + shopping-cart.tpl, so if you need to add something on the page ajax it's not the right way, but you will probably need to extend the **_assignSummaryInformations()** function in the **ParentOrderController** and add any variable you need to.

Unluckily the cart flow it's one of the most complex/long of the entire Prestashop system and it's not an easy task to implement new functionality, but the only way it's to go through the code of the CartController/Cart/OrderController classes and see where you really need to add new parameter. (remember to use the override system, to avoid unreadable code changes!)

Comment: I'm deeply grateful for your detailed answer. As you can see, I can't mark it as usefull now... :/

Comment: I use override with any changes (for made universal module)

I've extended _assignSummaryInformations() function in the ParentOrderController by add line and pass variable using smarty->assign

And it works fine, but only after refresh page. If only I use for example + button and ajax recount the values and display it, my veriable is lost in the JS.

Comment: I've found that if I add the same veriable in the Cart Class in the getSummaryDetails function by extending the return of this function it works totally fine ( after refresh and after + button) !

Comment: But I don't want to override the Cart class in this way, becouse it then will faill install if only Presta change the class.

Comment: Maybe you can try create your own hook, perhaps it would be easier. Here's some useful links : http://www.team-ever.com/ajoutez-des-hooks-personnalises-a-votre-prestashop/ (tutorial), and http://www.team-ever.com/boutique/createhook-module-dajout-de-hooks-a-prestashop/ (free module, allows you to create hooks on Prestashop 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook `actionCartListOverride`.
Or simply modify on the method `displayAjax` in `controllers/front/CartController.php`
You will find a `$result` array in which you could add your variables.

Comment: Thank you for hint. I've to admit I forgot about CartController.php :)
I focused on cart.php class and parentOrder controller

Comment: Do you know where I can find the list of hooks for 1.6 version ? With small description would be best. On official PS site there is only list for 1.5

Comment: This is the best link I could find http://cyrilchalamon.fr/prestashop-1-6-la-liste-des-hooks/

Comment: but there is no actionCartListOverride for example.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a complete list, but you can search for `actionCartListOverride` in PrestaShop code to see the parameters that it takes, you can find it in `CartController::displayAjax`